# Are Pandas' dataframes (Python) closer to R's dataframes or datatables?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, data.table

To understand my question, I should first point out that R datatables aren't just R dataframes with syntaxic sugar, there are important behavioral differences : column assignation/modification by reference in datatables avoids the copying of the whole object in memory (see the example in [this quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-data-frame-and-data-table-in-R-programming-language/answer/Andreas-Santucci)) as it is the case in dataframes.

I've found on multiple occasions that the speed and memory differences that arise from `data.table`'s behavior is a crucial element that allows one to work with some big datasets while it wouldn't be possible with `data.frame`'s behavior.

Therefore, what I'm wondering is : in Python, how do `Pandas`' dataframes behave in this regard ?

Bonus question : if Pandas' dataframes are closer to R dataframes than to R datatables, and have the same down side (a full copy of the object when assigning/modifying column), is there a Python equivalent to R's `data.table` package ?

---

**EDIT per comment request :** Code examples :

R dataframes :

```
# renaming a column
colnames(mydataframe)[1] <- "new_column_name"
```

R datatables :

```
# renaming a column
library(data.table)
setnames(mydatatable, 'old_column_name', 'new_column_name')
```

In Pandas :

```
mydataframe.rename(columns = {'old_column_name': 'new_column_name'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: as one who is not an `R` user - you may want to explain further the differences of dataframes versus datatables besides a single downside. I fear this question may be too broad. however, have you looked into `numpy`? `pandas` works very closely with it

Comment: Basically, if you want to change the name of a column in an R dataframe, the memory handling of the operation means the whole dataframe will at one point exist twice in memory. R datatables have a different behavior which will avoid this unnecessary process, the object will always exist only once. R datatables have other differences with R dataframes (such as aggregation features, and a different syntax), but they are irrelevant to the question as I'm mostly curious about how the memory is handled in Pandas dataframes.

Comment: Your question is very important. It will become clearer if you can provide example code of manipulation of a column of a data.frame so that one can see how best to accomplish the same thing with python pandas dataframe.

Comment: There you go, please see the edit of the question.

Comment: Seems very likely that any operation offering the `inplace` option can do it ... in place.

Comment: True. It seems maybe not, though, considering this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47097979/4348534 (and the question comments too)

Comment: @Frank from what I've understood, `inplace=True` often just means pointers to underlying data are moved around, and the *python* object keeps it's identity, but it doesn't prevent the copying of data

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah ok, interesting.

Comment: @Frank of course, that may not be the case for something like re-naming columns (I hope it isn't...) but I know that it isn't a guarantee...

Comment: I think some operation on each of the elements of a column or operation involving 2 columns should be the test to compare memory usage and efficiency, rather than just resetting column names.

Comment: @fmalaussena that’s an inadequate description of what happens in R. While you will get a new data frame, the unchanged columns will share memory with the previous data frame.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pandas operates more like `data.frame` in this regard. You can check this using the [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) package; here's an example of its use in the Jupyter notebook:

First define a program that will test this:

```
%%file df_memprofile.py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def foo():
    x = np.random.rand(1000000, 5)
    y = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=list('abcde'))
    y.rename(columns = {'e': 'f'}, inplace=True)
    return y
```

Then load the memory profiler and run + profile the function

```
%load_ext memory_profiler
from df_memprofile import foo
%mprun -f foo foo()
```

I get the following output:

```
Filename: /Users/jakevdp/df_memprofile.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4     66.1 MiB     66.1 MiB   def foo():
     5    104.2 MiB     38.2 MiB       x = np.random.rand(1000000, 5)
     6    104.4 MiB      0.2 MiB       y = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=list('abcde'))
     7    142.6 MiB     38.2 MiB       y.rename(columns = {'e': 'f'}, inplace=True)
     8    142.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       return y
```

You can see a couple things:

1. when `y` is created, it is just a light wrapper around the original array: i.e. no data is copied.
2. When the column in `y` is renamed, it results in duplication of the *entire data array* in memory (it's the same 38MB increment as when `x` is created in the first place).

So, unless I'm missing something, it appears that Pandas operates more like R's dataframes than R's data tables.

---

Edit: Note that `rename()` has an argument `copy` that controls this behavior, and defaults to True. For example, using this:

```
y.rename(columns = {'e': 'f'}, inplace=True, copy=False)
```

... results in an inplace operation without copying data.

Alternatively, you can modify the `columns` attribute directly:

```
y.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
```

Comment: I think the profiler is a line off. I commented out the rename() line and I still get a 38MB increase at line 7: 

"7    158.4 MiB     38.1 MiB       #y.rename(columns = {'e': 'f'}, inplace=True)"

Comment: @Marmaduke I can't reproduce that. When I comment-out the line, the profiler skips it.

Comment: As you pointed out elsewhere, it was caching the old version. Restarting the kernel restored sanity.